# Windows Task Scheduler Not Running On Some Machines When Locked

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I create a bunch of window task scheduler events on multiple win7 & server 2012 machines. These machines automatically lock the user session after a period of time. Note, this is not logging out. These tasks are designed to only run if the user is logged in, regardless if the computer is locked.

On many machines it runs fine. On some few, the task refuses to trigger until the user unlocks the machine. And I cannot figure out why.

The tasks are setup with the following settings:

- Run only when the user is logged on.
- Trigger: This can be daily, hourly, weekly, on every day or every other day, etc.
- Action: Start a program, cmd with a bunch of arguments
- Condition: Start the task only if the computer is on AC power and stop if the computer switches to battery.
- Allow task to be run on demand.
- Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop.

I checked the task scheduler history of these tasks on the afflicted computers and it looks like the "Task Engine received message to start" event does not trigger until the user unlocks the machine. On the machines that work, that message occurs on the specified time exactly.

I also checked that the power options on these machines have Wake Timers enabled in the power options under Sleep, google gave that as an issue but it doesn't seem to apply here.